# [React Native][Android][Graphql][Cache] App cash when I navigate on other screen without any error

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, apollo-client

I have app working in ios but android app is crashing when I navigate on other screen. There is no any log on debugger. When I open android log i found something is wrong with it.  I have dynamic generate content according to api. Where navigation props are send to every component . Before it use to work. But with v6 navigation they have some some change so it didn't work out. App is crashing when I navigate from dynamic generate content.
Any suggestion would be great.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: 1. check your setState statement in the target page 2. post the code of "original page" and "target page" please

Comment: Even though i comment out my whole code on both target and original page navigation let to crash app.

Comment: Are you using expo ? (if so, please execute `expo start -c` and then retry )

Comment: I'm using rn cli.

Comment: Try using `npm cache clean` and then retry

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @KenLee and replaying. Now, I know why app is crashing. I have dynamic generate content according to api. Where navigation props are send to every component . Before it use to work. But with v6 navigation they have some some change so it didn't work out.  App is crashing when I navigate from dynamic generate content. Now, I know real problem. I'm looking for solution.